# Sitecore 9.0.2 SXA 1.7.1 Creative Exchange Live Hangs

Tags: sxa

I am trying to set up Creative exchaneg live on my website using the document below

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/modify-your-site-design-with-creative-exchange-live.html

i added two classes to MyTheme\sass\component-richtext-content.scss

```
.text-highlight-red{
    text-align:left ;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.text-highlight-blue{
    text-align:left ;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

The sass-watch task to complie scss to css does not seem to be doing anything except for the warning gulp.run() has been deprecated

[image]

Any help would be great

Comment: Thanks for your reply @HarshBaid , How do i compile scss to css if the tasks are not working

Comment: I dont have list of the tasks handy right now but may be is `scss-components` gulp task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch tasks are live running tasks, this doesn't look like it is hungup but its listening to file changes.. As soon as you save anything it will upload them to Sitecore. Try using ctrl+s once on any of the files.

Comment: no luck with crtl + s

Comment: You need to use ctrl+s on a scss file while the watch tasks are running. If watch is stopped then nothing will get uploaded.

Comment: worked like a charm , thanks a lot! , am a sitecore SXA newbie

Comment: Sure no worries.. same here ;)